# How would I pull three pieces of text from a firebase database and display them in one textView?

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, textview

I've no problem getting the data from the firebase database. But how would you pull the different bits of data in to one textView like so....

[image]

Comment: Store them in a variable then can't you perform concatenation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
mRef.child("1").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilder.append(dataSnapshot.child("club").getValue().toString());
                stringBuilder.append(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
                stringBuilder.append(dataSnapshot.child("number").getValue().toString());
                myTextView.setText(stringBuilder);
                //or
                //myTextView.append(dataSnapshot.child("club").getValue().toString());                
                //myTextView.append(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());             
                //myTextView.append(dataSnapshot.child("number").getValue().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```